# Bind a repeater to an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my page_load I have called an object and am trying to bind it to a repeater, like so:

```
TestProgram myProgram = new TestProgram("5");

program_list.DataSource = myProgram;
program_list.DataBind();
```

and my repeater looks like

```
<asp:Repeater id="program_list" runat="server"> 
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("status").ToString().Trim() %>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Any idea why it isn't working?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What's happening at run-time?

Comment: And what does `TestProgram` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasource has to be a collection-type.

Try using a list.

```
TestProgram myProgram = new TestProgram("5");

List<TestProgram> programs = new List<TestProgram>{myProgram};

program_list.DataSource = programs;
program_list.DataBind();
```

Comment: When I try that I get the following error:

`System.ArgumentException: An invalid data source is being used for program_list. A valid data source must implement either IListSource or IEnumerable`

Comment: Nevermind, I mis-typed something, it worked perfectly, THANK YOU.